# Can I use google image "search results" in commercial apps?

Tags: google-image-search, copyright-display

I understand that there's a possibility of copyright infringement if I download any image on google image search and use It without asking for permission. But what if I use the search result itself does it still apply?

**Example:**
If I made an app that users can search products by name. And to show the product image, I simply use the user's input and grab the first result from google image and show it to the user. Does this count as fair use?